# How do you pass a test with XCUITest? iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, uitest, xctestcase

So I have this XCTestCase, it runs a simple function and I'm satisfied with the results, but every time the function ends, it displays "TEST FAILED" and shut down the app.

One more thing, I tried to change the continueAfterFailure boolean to true and yet it still shut down the app after failure...

I couldn't find a solution yet, hope someone can help me :)

Thanks

Update:
Here's the code:

```
func loginSuccess (element: XCUIElement) {
//Entering invalid input to the text field
//App has validator a that doesn't let the input in
element.typeText("!@#$%^")

XCTAssertTrue((element.value as? String == ""), "Test Passed!")

if element.value as? String == "" {
    print ("Test Passed!") //This line works every run
} else {
    XCTFail("Invalid text can be inserted") //Managed to force fail and succeded, but not pass.
}
```

}

Comment: Add a test failure breakpoint to see what makes the test failed.

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing the code/log. Show us the code and output.

Comment: Hey guys, I edited the post and added the code of the small function.
I hope its clear, if not - tell me and I'll add additional information..

Anyways, after running the XCTAssertTrue the function goes on and enter the if statement

Comment: @Leo There's a function called testExample the only thing it does is calls loginSuccess function. after loginSuccess is done, it goes back to testExample and then finish the function. when it reaches the last curly braces it shows test failed, debugging does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have things reversed. `XCTAssertTrue` evaluates that an expression is true and logs the provided message and fails the test if the expression is false.